# What type of exception to throw for custom errors?

Tags: php, exception

I have the following script.

According to http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php, You should not throw a PDOException from your own code.

But I want the same catch to be performed whether a PDOException or the exception that I threw for an invalid foo.

I've also been told that I should never catch the generic Exception, but only catch specific Exceptions.

How should this be implemented?

```
 try {
    db::db()->beginTransaction();

    //Do a bunch of queries, and a PDO exception will be thrown upon error

    if($foo($bar)) {throw new Exception('Invalid foo.');}

    db::db()->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    db::db()->rollBack();
    //Maybe do some other stuff
}
```

Comment: Don't think there is anything wrong with generic Exceptions. You could throw and catch RuntimeException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
try {
    db::db()->beginTransaction();

    //Do a bunch of queries, and a PDO exception will be thrown upon error

    if($foo($bar)) {throw new RuntimeException('Invalid foo.');}

    db::db()->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    db::db()->rollBack();
    //Maybe do some other stuff
} catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    //foo invalid
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  So, if I wish to rollback upon a `RuntimeException`, just duplicate the code in both catch statements?

Comment: Or just throw and catch a generic Exception. Or put the roll back code in a function and call the function in both places.

Comment: Last question.  Any reason I wouldn't want to throw a RuntimeException, and catch a generic Exception?

Comment: Well with a general Exception, you would be catching ALL exceptions including the PDOException and other Exceptions that could be thrown from other parts of the code. Which may not be what you want, you may want to do something different with each type

Comment: Sorry for continuing, but didn't expect your response.  So, why would I consider to "just throw and catch a generic Exception" as you earlier suggested?

Comment: So you catch them all and handle them all the same in one single catch block.

Comment: Ah, so only don't do so if I wish to handle each type of exception differently?